# Is it possible to call a .sql file in a doctrine migration?

Tags: sql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to call an .sql file in a migration class?

I could not find anything on that topic.

Comment: I don't think you can. You should launch it after your migration. What contains this sql file?

Comment: it creates stored procedures and views and it is dynamically created

Answer (score 18):

Yes, just put that .sql file and refer it from you migration class.

```
$this->addSql(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/sql-dump.sql'));
```

Comment: Does this refer to Doctrine 1.2.? I can't find this option :/

Comment: What if SQL contains several queries divided by semicolon?

Comment: ^ It works with multiple queries separated by semi-colons in the included SQL file (at least in Symfony 3.x; most probably works in Symfony 2.8+ as well ... just test it out).

Comment: I doesn't work with SQLite, because Doctrine calls the query() method, which doesn't support multiple statements in a single string, and will execute only the first one. Multiple statements are supported only with the exec() method. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php

Comment: Does not work with "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "3.2.1",

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but it is still the only real hit when I googled for it. The above answer can be slightly improved. It's a simple thing, but you might not think of it. If you have a sql file that contains multiple queries divided by semicolon, you can explode the contents on semicolon.

```
<?php

foreach (explode(';', file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/sql-dump.sql')) as $sql) {
    $this->addSql($sql);
}
```

Comment: What if there will be `;` inside sql query? It may be not safe. May be ";\n" should be better.

Comment: No need for this, as this (`$this->addSql(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/sql-dump.sql'));`) works in case of multiple queries separated by semi-colons.

Comment: I approve @luchaninov 's answer.
This can work for a simple pet project, but is not robust for a production-grade application:
- stored procedures will break
- a single comment with a semicolon "-- This column to store blabiboduc; null means no blabiboduc on this entry" will break

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQLite and want to execute a .sql file which cointains multiple statements separated by semicolon, I suggest using this code:

```
$this->connection->exec(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/sql-dump.sql'));
```

This beacuse if you use addSql() method, Doctrine will call the query() method, which doesn't support multiple statements in a single string, and will execute only the first one. Multiple statements are supported only with the exec() method. See: php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php

Answer (score 1):

For MySQLi I used:

```
$this->connection->getWrappedConnection()->getWrappedResourceHandle()->multi_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

**After doing some research this works for me**
I am using
doctrine-migrations-bundle: `"^3.0"`
symfony version: `5.4.12`
PostgreSQL version: `14.5`

**Procedure**
pq_dump:

```
pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only -U postgres -h localhost db_name > file_name.sql
```

Migrations:

```
public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
    $this->connection->getNativeConnection()->exec(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'./../Sql/file_name.sql'));
}
```

**Note:** Make sure this line is comment out in your sql file.
**SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);**